# Check if outlook folder exists

Tags: outlook

Following **vb.net code** checks if ARS folder exists in Outlook.

Following code works very well.

But I need a better code.

Better code means without using **On error goto** statement.

Comment: Why did you remove your code?

Answer (score 1):

VBA does not have structured exception handling (try/catch in C++, C#, VB.Net or try/except in Delphi). Since MAPIFolder.Folders.Item raises an exception if the specified folder is not found, VBA can only handle exceptions using "on error goto".

In VBA.Net, try something like the following (off the top of my head):

```
Try
   myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders("ARS")
Catch
  myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add("ARS")
End Try
```