# Generate Outlook folders/subfolders under Inbox based on pattern in Excel columns

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found code online https://www.slipstick.com/macros/Create%20subfolders%20at%20multiple%20levels.txt to batch create folders and subfolders within Outlook and ran it and it all works okay.

I want to convert it to work in shared mailboxes.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub MoveSelectedMessages()
    Dim objParentFolder As Outlook.Folder ' parent
    Dim newFolderName 'As String
    Dim strFilepath
    
    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
    Dim xlWkb As Object ' As Workbook
    Dim xlSht As Object ' As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Object 'Range

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    strFilepath = xlApp.GetOpenFilename
    If strFilepath = False Then
        xlApp.Quit
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
      
    Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilepath)
    Set xlSht = xlWkb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim iRow As Integer
     
    iRow = 2
    
'select starting parent
Dim parentname
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

Set objParentFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Set olApp = Nothing
Set Ns = Nothing
Set olShareName = Nothing

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set Ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olShareName = Ns.CreateRecipient("support@clientfirstsolutions.co.uk") '/// Owner's email address

Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)

While xlSht.Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""
parentname = xlSht.Cells(iRow, 1)
newFolderName = xlSht.Cells(iRow, 2)
            
            
 If parentname = "Inbox" Then
 Set objParentFolder = Folder
    Else
 Set objParentFolder = Folder.Folders(parentname)
 End If
On Error Resume Next

Dim objNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(newFolderName)

If objNewFolder Is Nothing Then
    Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName)
End If
    
    iRow = iRow + 1

 ' make new folder the parent
 ' Set objParentFolder = objNewFolder
    
  Set objNewFolder = Nothing
Wend
     
    xlWkb.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlWkb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set objParentFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

It asks you to select a formatted Excel doc and then creates the folders/subfolders based on the Excel file.

It doesn't create nested folders it just creates them all within the root inbox folder. It could be the `Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)` reverts everything back to the root inbox rather than nesting them as it did in the user mailbox.

| Parent Folder | Folder Name |
| --- | --- |
| Inbox | SubFolder |
| SubFolder | SubFolder01 |
| SubFolder01 | SubFolder01a |
| SubFolder01a | SubFolder01aA |
| SubFolder01a | SubFolder01aB |
| SubFolder01a | SubFolder01aC |
| SubFolder01a | SubFolder01aD |
| SubFolder01a | SubFolder01aE |

Debug Window:
parentname: Inbox
newFolderName: 1. Company
parentname: Inbox
objParentFolder.name: Inbox
newFolderName: 1. Company
objNewFolder.name: 1. Company
objParentFolder.name: 1. Company
parentname: 1. Company
newFolderName: 2023-24
parentname: 1. Company
objParentFolder.name: 1. Company
newFolderName: 2023-24
objNewFolder.name: 2023-24
objParentFolder.name: 2023-24
parentname: 2023-24
newFolderName: Q1 M1 - June
parentname: 2023-24
objParentFolder.name: 2023-24
newFolderName: Q1 M1 - June
objNewFolder.name: Q1 M1 - June
objParentFolder.name: Q1 M1 - June
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 1.Accounts
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
objParentFolder.name: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 1.Accounts
objNewFolder.name: 1.Accounts
objParentFolder.name: 1.Accounts
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 2.Sales
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
objParentFolder.name: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 2.Sales
objNewFolder.name: 2.Sales
objParentFolder.name: 2.Sales
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 3.Purchase
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
objParentFolder.name: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 3.Purchase
objNewFolder.name: 3.Purchase
objParentFolder.name: 3.Purchase
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 4.Expenses
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
objParentFolder.name: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 4.Expenses
objNewFolder.name: 4.Expenses
objParentFolder.name: 4.Expenses
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 5.Payroll
parentname: Q1 M1 - June
objParentFolder.name: Q1 M1 - June
newFolderName: 5.Payroll
objNewFolder.name: 5.Payroll
objParentFolder.name: 5.Payroll
Done.

Comment: The code cannot run. `folder` is not declared and `Ns` is not set. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72859409/edit) the question to put in [mcve].

Comment: Amended code to make it reproducible - sorry about that

Comment: Do the subfolders in column A exist or do you expect them to be created in the code?

Comment: I'd like them all to be created, ill show an example of the spreadsheet below:

ParentFolder | FolderNames
Inbox              Folder01
Folder01         SubFolder01
SubFolder01   SubFolder01a
SubFolder01a SubFolder01aA

Comment: You bypass the error when the column A subfolder does not exist under the inbox with `On Error Resume Next`. You have to address bypassed errors unless purposefully bypassing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an outlook folder exists; if not create it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365384/check-if-an-outlook-folder-exists-if-not-create-it)

Comment: Ah I have no idea I just found the code online here:

https://www.slipstick.com/macros/Create%20subfolders%20at%20multiple%20levels.txt

Also added the table in the question which might help to visualise it a bit - not sure if I've used the normal naming convention to how people describe things so please let me know if it's understandable or not.

Comment: When you see "objNewFolder.name: 1. Company", `objNewFolder` would have been created. Uncomment `Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objNewFolder` to go to it.

Comment: False Alarm, that was for my personal folder apologies, do I need to uncomment the stuff surrounding the support email?

Comment: Yes, uncomment the shared mailbox code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to change the following part from the code:

```
 If parentName = "Inbox" Then
 Set objParentFolder = Folder 
    Else
 Set objParentFolder = Folder.Folders(parentName)
 End If
```

To check whether a folder exists correctly you can use the `Folders` property. But if the folder doesn't exists an exception/error will be thrown. To handle such case you can use the following construction in the code:

```
Dim objNewFolder As Outlook.Folder

On Error Resume Next
Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(newFolderName)

If objNewFolder Is Nothing Then
    Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName)
End If
```

Comment: Hi there, I forgot that I was messing around with the code and left in some bits that didn't work as it did, I have now edited it as advised above and got it working however it doesn't create nested folders it just creates them all within the root inbox folder and believe it could be to do with the "Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)" line that might revert everything back to the root inbox rather than nesting them as it did in the user mailbox

Amended code has been added above which is now reproducible however as stated it only added it to the root inbox

Comment: You need to check whether such folder exists correctly. Please check the post updated. Have you run the code under the debugger attached and go through each line by checking the results of execution?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the results promised here
https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/create-outlook-folders-list-folder-names/
https://www.slipstick.com/macros/Create%20subfolders%20at%20multiple%20levels.txt

This generates nested folders for the example in the question.
Additionally, a subsequent entry of "Inbox" signals the start of a new set of nested folders.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub GenerateFoldersFromExcelColumns()

    Dim objParentFolder As Folder
    Dim parentName As String
    
    Dim objInboxFolder As Folder
    
    Dim objNewFolder As Folder
    Dim newFolderName As String
    
    Dim xlApp As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim xlWkb As Object ' Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSht As Object ' Excel.Worksheet
    
    Dim filePath As Variant
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    filePath = xlApp.GetOpenFilename
    If filePath = False Then
        xlApp.Quit
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
      
    Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Set xlSht = xlWkb.Worksheets(1)
    
    iRow = 2
    
    'select starting parent
    Set objInboxFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    ' Dim olShareName As Recipient
    'Shared email address
    ' Set olShareName = Session.CreateRecipient("support@clientfirstsolutions.co.uk") 
    ' Debug.Print "olShareName: " & olShareName
    ' Set objInboxFolder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)
    
    While xlSht.Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""
        
        parentName = xlSht.Cells(iRow, 1)
        Debug.Print "parentname: " & parentName
        
        newFolderName = xlSht.Cells(iRow, 2)
        Debug.Print "newFolderName: " & newFolderName
        
        If parentName = "Inbox" Then
        
            Set objParentFolder = objInboxFolder
            
            Debug.Print "parentname: " & parentName
            Debug.Print "objParentFolder.name: " & objParentFolder.name
            Debug.Print "newFolderName: " & newFolderName
            
            ' Alternative code to avoid On Error Resume Next
            ' Check if an Outlook folder exists; if not create it
            '  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365384
            
            On Error Resume Next
            ' Try to create the folder without verification
            ' Bypass error when folder exists
            Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName)
            On Error GoTo 0 ' As soon as possible after On Error Resume Next
            
            Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(newFolderName)
            Debug.Print "objNewFolder.name: " & objNewFolder.name
            
            ' for debugging
            'Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objNewFolder
            
        ElseIf parentName = objParentFolder.name Then
        
            Debug.Print "parentname: " & parentName
            Debug.Print "objParentFolder.name: " & objParentFolder.name
            Debug.Print "newFolderName: " & newFolderName
            
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName)
            On Error GoTo 0 ' As soon as possible after On Error Resume Next
            
            Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(newFolderName)
            Debug.Print "objNewFolder.name: " & objNewFolder.name
            
            ' for debugging
            'Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objNewFolder
            
        Else
            
            Set objParentFolder = objParentFolder.Parent
            
            Debug.Print "parentname: " & parentName
            Debug.Print "objParentFolder.name: " & objParentFolder.name
            Debug.Print "newFolderName: " & newFolderName
            
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName)
            On Error GoTo 0 ' As soon as possible after On Error Resume Next
            
            Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(newFolderName)
            Debug.Print "objNewFolder.name: " & objNewFolder.name
            
            ' for debugging
            'Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objNewFolder
            
        End If
        
        iRow = iRow + 1
        
        ' make new folder the parent
        Set objParentFolder = objNewFolder
        Debug.Print "objParentFolder.name: " & objParentFolder.name
        
        ' No purpose in this case
        '  but is typical with On Error Resume Next logic
        '  when there is a test for Nothing
        'Set objNewFolder = Nothing
                    
    Wend

exitRoutine:

    xlWkb.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    
    Set xlSht = Nothing
    Set xlWkb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
        
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Niton, thank you for your assistance, I tried to run the code and got a Syntax error for the following line:

Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders.Add(nOption Explicit

Comment: @MasonGrogan Looks like you made a misclick copying the code.

Comment: Hi I have had a chance to test your code and it doesn't seem to add anything to the mailbox, this is the debug from the immediate window:

Comment: Uncomment the shared mailbox code that I commented for my testing.

Comment: Hi Niton, I have tried this and get an error advising "The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found." and then highlights "Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(newFolderName)" I will look into how to debug in the editor and see if I can resolve.