# Create Outlook folders (with subfolders) per Excel list

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel file which lists folder names under my C (over 600 folders). This list is updated automatically if a new folder is created. If folder already exists nothing is done.

In Outlook, under Inbox - Folder "Production", I would like to create a new folder (if it does not exists) with name from column A.
Each folder in Outlook should be created with the same sub-folder structure.

For each Vsl Name under Excel/column A create subfolder as per attached structure:
[image]

I found the following macro.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub MoveSelectedMessages()
    Dim objParentFolder As Outlook.Folder ' parent
    Dim newFolderName 'As String
    Dim strFilepath
    
    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
    Dim xlWkb As Object ' As Workbook
    Dim xlSht As Object ' As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Object 'Range

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    strFilepath = xlApp.GetOpenFilename
    If strFilepath = False Then
        xlApp.Quit
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
      
    Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilepath)
    Set xlSht = xlWkb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim iRow As Integer
     
    iRow = 2
    
    'select starting parent
    Set objParentFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
 
    Dim parentname

    While xlSht.Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""
        parentName = xlSht.Cells(iRow, 1)
        newFolderName = xlSht.Cells(iRow, 2)
    
        If parentName = "Inbox" Then
            Set objParentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Else
            Set objParentFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(parentName)
        End If
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim objNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(newFolderName)

        If objNewFolder Is Nothing Then
            Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName)
        End If
    
        iRow = iRow + 1

        ' make new folder the parent
        ' Set objParentFolder = objNewFolder
    
        Set objNewFolder = Nothing
    Wend
     
    xlWkb.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlWkb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set objParentFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The source describes the required format. [Create Outlook Folders from a List of Folder Names](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/create-outlook-folders-list-folder-names/)

Comment: If you have the flexibility to adjust your format, see if you can apply [Generate Outlook folders/subfolders under Inbox based on pattern in Excel columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859409).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be resetting the `objParentFolder` variable on every step of the loop instead of keeping the same value. Do not reset it in the loop - use a local (to the loop) variable instead.